# The Richest Man in Babylon Explanation

Tags: meaning

I am reading "The Richest Man in Babylon" but could not get the meaning of the following sentences:

> Provide also that thy family may not want should the Gods call thee to their realms. For such protection it is always possible to make provision with small payment at regular intervals. Therefore the provident man delays not in expectation of a large sum becoming available for such a wise purpose.

Anyone please rephrase them so I can understand them easily. Thank you

Comment: It means *buy life insurance*.

Comment: Brilliant, Dan. Brilliant!

Comment: Substitute *go wanting* (i.e., be in need) for *want*. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @DanBron Or a piggy bank.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I considered that, but the text says *payment* as opposed to *savings*.

Comment: @DanBron You don't pay your piggy bank? How cruel of you—that's cruelty to animals **and** slavery all in once!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a paraphrase:

(I'm assuming this occurs within a list or chapter on provisions since it begins with the words "provide also")

Also, make sure to provide for your family in case of your death so that they do not lack what they need. You can do this by putting aside small amounts of money on a regular basis (presumably either by saving or by purchasing insurance).

[Therefore, a good provider can count on having a decent/large sum of money available without delay in case of need.] -- for a better paraphrase of this bit see the comment below by Janus. I think they are more accurate than I am on this part.

edited for accuracy

Comment: Your last sentence does not say the same as the one in the quote. The quote admonished that a wise man should not wait for a huge windfall to set anything aside for future safeguarding, but does it straight away with whatever he can spare.

Comment: You're right -- I had another read.

Comment: "the provident man" is not 'a good provider'. He is a wise and far-sighted man.

Answer (score 0):

> Start a fund to provide your family's needs after your death, so that they do not face financial hardship. Build this fund now by saving part of your income regularly and consistently overtime. A man with farsight and planning does this. He does not gamble with his family's financial protection by depending on some large payment in the future.

Summary: A provident man would take on a life insurance policy whose specific purpose is to provide a lumpsum payment to his beneficiaries (family) upon his death. He would have to save into the policy diligently and consistently over a specific period or throughout his life.

Farsight means the ability to anticipate the risks of financial distress one's family faces incase one passes on.The family would be forced to sell valuable assets and property just to live on. A life insurance policy prevents exactly that and helps the family preserve wealth.